# How can I catch a guy who always runs from me (because I shot him)?

Tags: dragons-dogma

I shot a guy who had a quest for me, and got put in the dungeon for it. Now he runs from me every time he sees me, and I can't talk to him to pick up the quest.

Is there a way to make him stop running from me and give me his quest?

(The guy is Fornival in Gran Soren)

Comment: He should calm down after a couple of in-game days, just "sleep until morning" a couple of times.

Comment: @Tzarium That's what I thought too, but so far that doesn't appear to be the case. Do you know how many days you have to wait?

Comment: From what I've read, it's eight or ten days.

Comment: @Tzarium Thanks, I'll give that a try later on and if let you know if it works or not. If it does, you should post it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: try knocking him down and when he is on the floor try to talk to him? Such tactics that is used in catching the thief quest.